# How to tag jump in new tab, if target file not in active tabs, else switch to exists tab?

Tags: tags, navigation

I use the mapping below:

```
nnoremap <silent><C-]> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T
```

But it will open duplicate file in multiple tabs.

I have two questions:

- Has vim built-in functions which can return a list of tab files? like `:tabs` command
- How to get tag's filename under the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

> Has vim built-in functions which can return a list of tab files? like :tabs command

You'll have to do some parsing, but you can use `let myVar = execute('tabs')` for this.

> How to get tag's filename under the cursor?

I don't think there's a built in way to do this but here's a quick and dirty first stab at a function that will do it:

```
function! ReturnTagFileUnderCursor()
   try
      let tag = expand('<cword>')
      let tagString = split(execute("tselect ".tag), "\n")[1]
      let tagString = matchstr(tagString, '[^/\\]*$')
      return tagString
   catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E426/
      echohl ERROR
      echo "Tag not found!"
      echohl NORMAL
      return ""
   endtry
endfunction
```

Note: This will always take the first result if there are duplicate tags. Also it returns just the filename, but you can adjust the regex to get the whole path if desired.

See `:h execute()` and `:h tselect` for more info.